# How to download headlines from GDELT database

Tags: database, news

I tried to use GDELT from Google BigQuery, but I can't find Headline column there.
Can you please tell me how to do it on BigQuery or using Python?
I need data from 2015 to 2023 by keywords.
Thank you!